# git log - find additions of a specified string

Tags: git

How can I search through my git history for commits containing **additions only** of a specified string?

For example, how could I find all commits that contain additions of `System.out.println` or `debugger`.

I know of the `-S` argument that can be supplied to `git log`, but it includes all commits containing **additions or subtractions** of the specified string.

Is there a natural way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following one -

To search the commit log for the given string:

`git log --all --grep='specific string'`

To search the actual content of commits in the repository:

`git grep 'specific string' $(git rev-list --all)`

It will give all the instances of the given text, the containing file name, and the commit.

Hope this is what you want.

**Updated**

Check the following two links also -

[git-grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

[Search a git repo like a ninja](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The first command doesn't exclude subtractions of the supplied string though.  The second command uses `git grep`, which seems to search content in the current workspace instead of searching through git history.  I'm specifically looking for the point where the addition was introduced.  I might not have been clear about that - I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Can you please explain "command doesn't exclude subtractions of the supplied string though" ?

Do you mean that -  which file is newly added ? If some file is deleted in the same commit that file will not display - is it ?????

Comment: I mean, for example, that it will show commits where "System.out.println" was added to a file and it will also show commits where "System.out.println" was removed from a file.  I'd only like the commits where it was added.

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I am running into the same problem.